# How to return to first function after call to third function

Tags: c++, return, exit, void

Basically, what I want to do is this:

From one function void A() I call another function void B(). B in turn calls on the function void C(). How can I, after some statement, return to the last called line in A from C? If I type return I return to B, but I don't want this code in B to be executed if the statement in C is true, I want to end up in A. I could change C to bool C() and check this in B, but I'd rather not.

So, is there some type of double return I could use? The exit-keyword exits the entire program which is not what I want to do.

Comment: Almost certainly you are trying to do something that can be done better with a bit more careful thought. Why not describe the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Ok. I'm making a small text based game. So the function A is basically what I call action(), where the character in turn makes his move. From action() I can call to fight(), if I want to fight another character. fight() is turn based, so for each characters turn in the fight you call to hit(). In hit() I want to add a input choice to run instead of fight. When I run I want to exit fight(), but not action().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is wrong with this one?

```
void A() {
  B();
}

void B() {
  if (!C()) return;
  ...
}

bool C() {
  ..
}
```

Comment: I ended up with this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is not directly possible to return to anything but a function's immediate caller (B, in this case) unless you use `longjmp`, which I believe is not advisable in C++. However, if the reason you want to skip B is that an error has occurred in C and the error can only be handled by A, you can use exceptions (warning: incomplete example; my C++ is getting rusty):

```
#include <stdexcept>

void A() {
    try {
        B();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        // You'll get here if C throws
    }
}

void B() {
    C();
}

void C() {
    if (someCondition)
        return; // Sends you to B
    else
        throw std::exception; // Sends you to A since B does not contain a try/catch
}
```

But please do *not* use exceptions for regular (non-exceptional) control flow; use it only for actual error situations.

Answer (score 1):

You've given `C` the wrong signature. It should be `bool C` and return a "success" indicator to `B` which then returns immediately to `A` or continues as appropriate.

Comment: This is what I was thinking too. Just wanted to avoid it because I then have to change a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, with a simple assembly trick:

```
leave
leave
ret
```

Basically this code goes through B's stack frame to obtain the return address in A, then resumes execution from there. Sample program (it's C, but you don't mind, do you? ;) ):

```
void C()
{
    printf("Inside C...\n");
    __asm__("leave");
    __asm__("leave");
    __asm__("ret");
}

void B()
{
    printf("Calling C...\n");
    C();
    printf("Returned from C...\n");
}

int main()
{
    B();
}
```

Here's the output:

```
blackbear@blackbear-laptop:~$ ./a.out 
Calling C...
Inside C...
blackbear@blackbear-laptop:~$
```

Comment: @pezcode: ah, I've misunderstood your comment. Well, I don't think what the OP's asking is standard C, so it will surely depend on something. This is _a_ solution, the best I can think of :)

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this, but I don't recommend it cause there all kinds of issues with this:

```
jmp_buf env;

A()
{
  jmp_buf env;
  if ( !setjmp( &env ) )
  {
    B();
  }
  ...
}

B()
{
  C();
}

C()
{
  if ( for_some_reason )
  {
    longjmp( &env, 1 );
  }
}
```